# UML association - what is the code equivalent of a 'role'?

Tags: java, oop, uml

What is the code equivalent of a UML associative role? For example, I have the below UML diagram:

[image: UML example diagram]

There is an associative arrow from Graph class to GraphNode class. Next to the associative arrow is the text `-nodesMap 0..*`. I understand that this is an associative relationship with the role name nodesMap. The relationship is from 0 to many. I have two questions about this diagram and its code equivalents:

1. What does the dash before the role mean? Is nodesMap private?
2. What is nodesMap in the Graph class? Is it a member of the Graph class? Further, if it is a member, what is its type and why isn't it listed with the other variables, like in the GraphNode class (for example, the component attribute)?

Comment: You should read https://bellekens.com/2011/08/10/uml-best-practice-attribute-or-association/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! This cleared things up immensely, great source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the dash before the role mean? Is nodesMap private?

yes, the notation is :

- `+` : public
- `-` : private
- `#` : protected
- `~` : package

> What is nodesMap in the Graph class? Is it a member of the Graph class?

Yes, for a language as Java *nodesMap* is an attribute. In UML that means the property end is own by *Graph*.

> Further, if it is a member, what is its type and why isn't it listed with the other variables, like in the GraphNode class (for example, the component attribute)?

Its type is a collection of *GraphNode*, because the target of the relation is the class *GraphNode* and the multiplicity is 0..* meaning any number ≥ 0. The way to support the collection is free without additional information saying if it is ordered and/or elements are unique etc

Note you can also represent that attribute among the other attributes in the class with `- nodesMap: GraphNode [0..*]`